# Protecting /index.html with .htaccess file

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

**I would like to use a `.htaccess` and a `.htpasswd` file to protect access to a website.**

The following code successfully brings up the auth dialog when visiting `mysite.com`. But when visiting `mysite.com/index.html` the auth dialog does not appear and the website can be accessed without protection.

**.htaccess**

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected"
Require valid-user
```

**What do I need to change to ensure that `mysite.com/index.html` is protected as well?**

---

I have tried adding:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
```

and also:

```
<Files "index.html">
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Neither make any difference to the problem.

Comment: What you have in the .htaccess should achieve that on its own already. I guess your “problem” here is simply that you have entered the credentials already when you accessed `mysite.com`? The browser will remember those credentials until it gets closed, and automatically send them for any other URLs from that same realm … Try opening `mysite.com/index.html` in a new, private tab, and see what happens then.

Comment: Nope, already tried that.

Comment: There is no reason why it should behave like that, based on those few lines of .htaccess code you have shown.

Comment: I've tried private Chrome window, which lets me access index.html without auth pop.up. However, both in Firefox and Safari I do get the pop-up for index.html, but the site is already loaded behind it.

Comment: That sounds as if some resource that you embedded into the index.html was triggering this then in FF and Safari, and not that main document itself.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try it with

AllowOverride AuthConfig

If I remember it right it is not activated on the default :)

you can get more information in the official apache doc

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html